# Apache basic auth alternative

Tags: linux, apache, http, video-streaming, ip-camera

I am using a axis camera which is served by apache2, the authentication mechanism is apache basic auth. Ssl is configured for the domain. The problem is that I cannot call an api for streaming using the embedded url for example:-

https://user:pass@sub.domain.com/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi

This is no longer supported by google as per this post and blocked by chrome.
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856

I tried by passing the credentials along with the url and it is also not working.

https://sub.domain.com/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?user=user&pwd=pass

This camera is running in a linux customer OS, is it possible to setup an alternative authentication which supports my needs.  Furthermore is it possible to by any other means?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may try

https://user:pass@sub.domain.com/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi

good luck

this is to add enough flesh to this post.